# How to know if a textfield is empty in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a basic app in swift (for learning purposes), in order to convert cat years into human years. So, there is a textbox named: **edadGatoTextField** where user can enter the cat's years, and then press **calcularEdadButtonPressed** button to see the converted years in **mensajeLabel**.

I was trying to add an **if** statement in order to print a message in **mensajeLabel** telling to the user that must enter a number to convert it.

--> So, bellow is the code, which should works, but **why I'm getting an error in: *if age*?**

*I ran my app as normal, but it crashes when hit **calcularEdadButtonPressed** while there isn't a number in **edadGatoTextField***

There is something related with optionals or unwrapped optionals.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var edadGatoTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var mensajeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imagenGatoImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func calcularEdadButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        var age = edadGatoTextField.text.toInt()

        // *** Bellow is the error! I'm trying to figure out if user
        // has not entered any number in order to display the message.

        if age { 

            age = age * 7

            mensajeLabel.text = "Your cat's age is \(age) years!"
            mensajeLabel.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()

            edadGatoTextField.resignFirstResponder()

            imagenGatoImageView.image = UIImage(named: "cat2.jpg")

        } else {

            mensajeLabel.text = "Please enter a number!"
            mensajeLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: A small suggestion: you are using method names like calcularEdadButtonPressed(). It might be usefull to pick a language and stick with it, instead of mixing them. So; 'calculateAgeButtonPressed()'. If you combine them you are bound to get confused at some point. Personally I like to only use English, seeing as the programming language itself is in English as well (.text, .textColor, etc.) and everyone on Stack Overflow will be able to read and understand the names when pasting example code.

Comment: Regarding @nhgrif answer, using **var** instead of **let** can save time and coding instead create another variable to calculate cat years.

Comment: Don't edit an answer into your question.  Just mark one as accepted.

Comment: @StevensGarcia Using `if var` saves not just coding time and lines of code, it's also more efficient as we only create one variable on the stack instead of two, and we only move memory from location a to b once instead of twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`age` is of type `Int?` (an optional `Int`), so is either an integer or `nil`. You cannot treat a `nil` comparison like a Boolean comparison in Swift `if` statements. You must explicitly check against `nil`:

```
if age != nil {
    let humanAge = age! * 7
    //...
} else {
    //...
}
```

But you should probably use optional binding instead, unless you have a reason not to:

```
if let age = edadGatoTextField.text.toInt() {
    let humanAge = age * 7
    //...
} else {
    //...
}
```

Comment: if age != nil { } will give error at line age = age * 7. I think the best way is later code snippet in your answer.

Comment: `if let age = edadGatoTextField.text.toInt()` will also give an error at the line `age = age * 7`, as `age` will be a constant. I was assuming that they would be able to refactor the content of the `if` statement themselves, but I'll edit my answer to clarify.

Comment: @Stuart I tried both methods and they work perfectly. Thanks for your great explanation.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems here.

First, `UITextField`'s `text` property is optional.  Unless you are manually setting it to an empty string every time you create it, it will be `nil` until the user has type something in it.

Second, `String`'s `toInt()` method returns an optional `Int?`.  If the `String` you're calling `toInt()` can't be parsed as an integer, `toInt()` returns `nil`.

And then we have the hurdle that Stuart's answer bumps into.  Using the `if let` pattern, we must then declare yet another variable inside the `if` body to multiply by seven, because `if let` declares a constant which cannot be modified.

We can resolve all three of these issues in a single line however.  We simply need to be aware that `if let` isn't the only available pattern.  We can use `if var`:

```
if var catAge = edadGatoTextField.text.toInt() {
    catAge *= 7
    // the rest of what you need to do
}
```

Comment: Never even knew about the `if var` statement

Comment: @nhgrif Excellent, I also didn't know you could use `var` in optional binding (I knew it was possible in function declarations, but I don't recall the documentation mentioning the same for `if`).

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

**You can check by this code if your textfield is empty or not?**

***Add target to your textfield***

```
     self.yourTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

***now you can bind the Function which you have wired with the target field.***

```
func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField){
      if textField.text == "" {
           //You can perfrom your activity here when textfield got blank or empty
      }
      else
      {
           //You can perfrom your activity here when textfield got not blank or not empty 
      }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if let age = edadGatoTextField.text.toInt() {
    // Calculate cat years    
} else {
    // Show error
}
```

If you look at docs UITextField.text is an implicitly unwrapped optional, so it may be nil if is not initialized. Due to 'if let' and optional chaining construct you will get 'age' if and only if text is not nil and is convertible to int otherwise it will be nil.